# Extracting a specific identifier from a column containing excess information

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, stringr

I'm trying to use stringr/dplyr to extract a pathway name from a table cell containing excess information. All cells in this table follow the same general format. Some examples are:

---

(R)-lactate from methylglyoxal: step 1/2. {ECO:0000256|ARBA:ARBA00005008, ECO:0000256|RuleBase:RU361179}.

---

(S)-dihydroorotate from bicarbonate: step 3/3. {ECO:0000256|ARBA:ARBA00004880}.

---

3,4',5-trihydroxystilbene biosynthesis

---

From these examples, I want to extract "(R)-lactate from methylglyoxal", "(S)-dihydroorotate from bicarbonate", and "3,4',5-trihydroxystilbene biosynthesis" respectively. I'm struggling to figure out which combination of regular expressions to use in order to accomplish this. I've been trying to use the positive look behind assertion `?<=...` along with `str_extract` to extract all information preceding the first ":", but I can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `sub(":.*", "", data)`

Comment: @G5W, how'd you handle the interesting `3,4',5` notation?

Answer (score 0):

please try the following pattern:

```
(?<=^)(.+?)(:|$)
```

(?<=^)  the first part is looking exclusively at the beginning of the sentence
(.+?)(:|$)   the second part is looking for at least one character before first ":" or end of sentence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRwTj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any lookarounds, you can match the values using:

```
^[^\r\n:]+
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\r\n:]+` Match 1+ chars other than newlines or `:`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DGIduA/1)

```
library(stringr)

s <- c("(R)-lactate from methylglyoxal: step 1/2. {ECO:0000256|ARBA:ARBA00005008, ECO:0000256|RuleBase:RU361179}.",
"(S)-dihydroorotate from bicarbonate: step 3/3. {ECO:0000256|ARBA:ARBA00004880}.",
"3,4',5-trihydroxystilbene biosynthesis")
str_extract(s, "^[^\\r\\n:]+")
```

Output

```
[1] "(R)-lactate from methylglyoxal"        
[2] "(S)-dihydroorotate from bicarbonate"   
[3] "3,4',5-trihydroxystilbene biosynthesis"
```